# Added scheduled reminder not showing in admin

Tags: scheduled-reminders, scheduled-job

I have been battling for 48 hours trying to figure out why schedule reminders I added are not showing up in admin.

Here's the screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/AZ1CoyMqDbH

Also, there are couple of errors in console, perhaps you guys have an idea when you spotted them.

The same error on "Setting - Schedule Jobs" admin https://www.screencast.com/t/JxHWb8MSlE57

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a double HTTPS - one of those is missing the colon between the https and backslashes.

Check **Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs**, and also `civicrm.settings.php` for `https//`.